# prove: $\dfrac{2^{n+1}+(-1)^n}{3}$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction

I am asked to prove this notation with induction for $n\in \mathbb{N}$:

real problem is to fill the area with tilings. and for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there are exactly so many chances to fill the area as the formula says:  $$\dfrac{2^{n+1}+(-1)^n}{3}$$

I started in this way:
Base Case: $n=1$:

$$\dfrac{ 2^2-1}{3} = 1$$

Inductive step: $n\rightarrow n+1$:

$$\dfrac{2^{n+2}+(-1)^{n+1}}{3} = help..$$

my problem is: what am i doing, i seem to have already proven it in this last step which is obviously wrong. what am i missing here in this proof?

thanks for help

Comment: Just at a guess... do you mean "prove that $2^{n+1}+(-1)^n$ is divisible by 3"?

Comment: @GlenO, no, real problem is to fill the area with tilings. and for $n$ there are exactly so many chances to fill the area as the formula above. i will update the question with this

Comment: You do not prove notation.

Comment: we understand what @doniyor wants to ask their is no need to downvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dfrac{2^{n+2}+(-1)^{n+1}}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{2^{n+1}\cdot2+(-1)^{n}\cdot(-1)}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{2^{n+1}\cdot2-(-1)^{n}}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{2^{n+1}\cdot(3-1)-(-1)^{n}}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{2^{n+1}\cdot(3)-2^{n+1}-(-1)^{n}}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{2^{n+1}\cdot(3)-(2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n})}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{2^{n+1}\cdot(3)}{3}-\dfrac{(2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n})}{3}$$

Proven.

Comment: thanks, but what does this proof say regarding tiles?

Comment: Could you point me to how to obtain S(n)=S(n−1)+2S(n−2) from above?

Comment: $S(n) \equiv \frac{2^{n+1} + (-1)^n}{3}$, how to get $S(n)=S(n−1)+2S(n−2)$?

Comment: May I know Where are you trying to get to from S(n+2)? Because it appears that both term above can't apply any assumptions.

Comment: are you talking about last line in my solution?

Comment: Yes. How to apply assumptions like S(n-1) to it?

Comment: in last line i am saying that both parts are divisible by 3 because as 1st part contain 3 in multiplication so it will divisible by 3 and 2nd part is based on induction's assumption that if expression holds true for n=1,2,3 then it will also hold true n=k and after that we try to prove that it should holds true for n=k+1.so in 2nd part is the same as n=k and we take it as it is holding true.This whole calculation for n=k+1 using n=k (where n=k is true).I hope now i am clear if you have any other doubt than mail me or discuss in chat

Comment: But isn't the second term you mentioned doesn't matched with S(k)?

Comment: sorry their was typo. I was writing (n+2)instead of (n+1).Now it has s(k).Thanks for mention my error

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\dfrac{2^{n+2}+(-1)^{n+1}}{3}=\dfrac{2^{n+1}+(-1)^n}{3}+\dfrac{2\cdot 2^n+2\cdot(-1)^{n-1}}{3}$$
(factorize the second term)

Comment: btw the problem is probably to get the "Number of ways to tile a $3$ X $(n-1)$ rectangle with $1$ X $1$ and $2$ X $2$ square tiles" or the "Number of ways to tile a $2$ X $(n-1)$ rectangle with $1$ X $2$ dominoes and $2$ X $2$ squares" or ... from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001045)".

Comment: Exactly this is the given problem!!!

Comment: @doniyor: so that this says that $S(n)=S(n-1)+2\;S(n-2)$ : to get the ways for a rectangle of length $n$ consider the ways for length $n-1$ added with $2$ times the ways for the length $n-2$.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you would need the n - 1 case.

$2^{n+1} + (-1)^n = (2^{n+1} + (-1)^n)(2 + -1) = 2^{n+2} + 2(-1)^n + -2^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1} = (2^{n+2} + (-1)^{n+1}) + 2(2^n + (-1)^{n-1}(-1)^2)$